# Getting elements from website using Selenium Basic Vba

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, automation

I am new to the Selenium Basic components and I am trying to get the element of the **"Expired"** button from the following link below, but I am not getting anything, the count is always 0.

https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiZGQzZDEzZjgtYzg3OS00ZDgxLWE5ZWMtODE0NGQ5Y2FjMjc0IiwidCI6ImQwMTUyOGY5LTQ3NDItNGJjYS05MDVmLWU3ZjIxZTJhNmM5MiIsImMiOjEwfQ%3D%3D

I am trying to get the element with Selenium Basic Vba and using the Edge as browser,

```
Dim edge as WebDriver
Set edge = new WebDriver
Set ele = edge.FindElementsByXPath("//ul/li/div/span")
```

but not getting anything, please help.

Comment: Additional information, I can get to the element in the Developer Tool inside the browser with the XPath
```//ul/li/div/span```
There should be 2 results, the 1st result is what I need

Comment: It is inside an iframe. You need to SwitchTo that iframe or navigate direct to its src `https://app.powerbi.com/13.0.16442.42/visualSandboxMinimal.html?=&plugin=ChicletSlicer1448559807354&locale=en-GB`